# vscode giving me invalid symbol error everywhere

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm going crazy, VSCode is giving me this error EVERYWHERE (including js files and .gitignore .dockerignore files, even for simple lines such as node_modules in .gitignore)

I need some ideas

my config file

```
{
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "One Monokai",
    "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
    "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.printWidth": 80,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false
}
```

My extensions are pretty standard

- prettier
- react snippets
- docker
- sass
- eslint
- some random themes
- editor config
- graphql
- auto-import

[image: Error Img]

Comment: Ha. Asked 36 mins ago. That's roughly when that first happened to me as well. Super annoying.

Comment: Are you on macOS 10.15 Catalina? This started happening to me right after the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue randomly appeared for me today as well.

This process worked to solve it on my system, although I don't know what actually caused the issue.

1. restart vscode
2. check for a vscode update
3. (optional) Restart system

   If 1-3 don't work you can try
4. In the command palette run Extensions: Disable All Installed Extension

Comment: Everything returned fine by just restarting everything randomly, thanks

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me when this issue started popping up **after installing macOS 10.15 Catalina**.

- Reinstall node.js using `nvm`, e.g. `nvm install 10 && nvm use 10` to install and use the latest node.js 10.x version (pick your preferred version)
- Reinstall `eslint` via `npm i -g eslint`
- Restart VS Code